# Where toDF in Spark-shell, how to use with Vector, Seq or other?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, spark-shell

I try some basic data types,

```
val x = Vector("John Smith", 10, "Illinois")
val x = Seq("John Smith", 10, "Illinois")
val x = Array("John Smith", 10, "Illinois")
val x = ...
val x = Seq( Vector("John Smith",10,"Illinois"), Vector("Foo",2,"Bar"))
```

but no one offer `toDF()`, even after `import spark.implicits._`.

My aim is to use someting as `x.toDF("name","age","city").show`

In the last example  the `toDF` exists, but error *"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"*.

---

NOTES:

- I am using Spark-shell with Spark v2.2.
- Need generic transformation based on colunm names parametrized in `toDF(names)`, **not** complex solutions as create Vector of `case class Person(name: String, age: Long, city: String)`

Expected result of show after toDF is

```
+----------+---+--------+
|      name|age|    city|
+----------+---+--------+
|John Smith| 10|Illinois|
+----------+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put values in tuple to create 3 columns

```
scala> Seq(("John Smith", "asd", "Illinois")).toDF("name","age","city").show
+----------+---+--------+
|      name|age|    city|
+----------+---+--------+
|John Smith|asd|Illinois|
+----------+---+--------+
```

Comment: I never used `val x = ("Hello", "world")`  with no qualifier... Now I see that it works (!), and  you are teaching me that is valid and his name is *tuple*. So, perhaps the best and simplest Spark DataFrame definition is **"DF is a Seq of Tuples"** (why no Guide say it?)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are looking for is.

```
val x = Array("John Smith", "10", "Illinois")
sc.parallelize(x).toDF()
```

the other way is,

```
val y = Seq("John Smith", "10", "Illinois")
Seq(y).toDF("value").show()
```

And this should work too.

```
Seq(Vector("John Smith","10","Illinois"), Vector("Foo","2","Bar")).toDF()
```

Comment: @PeterKrauss try this, it was issue of datatype mismatch.